# Make keeps using native gcc instead of Android NDK

Tags: linux, gcc, android-ndk, makefile

First of all, I know only basics about makefile and I'm new to Android NDK.

I've got x64 Linux Mint 17.1 and [Android NDK r8e](http://dl.google.com/androihttps://yadi.sk/d/r6dnof69enipod/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2), and I'm trying to build [NetHack for Android](https://github.com/gurrhack/NetHack-Android).

As stated in [README](https://github.com/gurrhack/NetHack-Android/blob/master/sys/android/README), basic idea is to modify makefile with local Android NDK path:

```
NDK = /path/to/android-ndk-r8d
SYSROOT=$(NDK)/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
CC = $(NDK)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$(SYSROOT)
```

But I keep getting this error:

> cc -m32 -o makedefs makedefs.o ./monst.o ./objects.o
>   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc

Apparently **/usr/bin/ld** is being used instead of **arm-linux-androideabi-ld**  and it doesn't look for **libgcc.a** in Android NDK folder.
Am I missing some environment variable or make argument?

Thanks.

### UPD1

Here's complete output:

```
touch ../src/config.h-t
/opt/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -DANDROID -Wno-format -fsigned-char -I../include -c monst.c
/opt/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/opt/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -DANDROID -Wno-format -fsigned-char -I../include -c objects.c
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rzhilich/Projects/NetHack-Android/util'
cc -m32 -Wno-format  -I../include   -c -o makedefs.o makedefs.c
makedefs.c: In function ‘do_rumors’:
makedefs.c:361:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  Fprintf(ofp,Dont_Edit_Data);
  ^
makedefs.c: In function ‘do_date’:
makedefs.c:560:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  Fprintf(ofp,Dont_Edit_Code);
  ^
makedefs.c: In function ‘do_dungeon’:
makedefs.c:1232:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  Fprintf(ofp,Dont_Edit_Data);
  ^
makedefs.c: In function ‘do_monstr’:
makedefs.c:1354:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
     Fprintf(ofp,Dont_Edit_Code);
     ^
makedefs.c: In function ‘do_permonst’:
makedefs.c:1395:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  Fprintf(ofp,Dont_Edit_Code);
  ^
makedefs.c: In function ‘do_objs’:
makedefs.c:1711:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  Fprintf(ofp,Dont_Edit_Code);
  ^
makedefs.c: In function ‘do_vision’:
makedefs.c:1866:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
     Fprintf(ofp,Dont_Edit_Code);
     ^
makedefs.c:1891:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
     Fprintf(ofp,Dont_Edit_Code);
     ^
cc -m32 -Wno-format  -I../include -c ../src/monst.c -o monst.o
cc -m32 -Wno-format  -I../include -c ../src/objects.c -o objects.o
cc -m32 -o makedefs makedefs.o ./monst.o ./objects.o
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [makedefs] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rzhilich/Projects/NetHack-Android/util'
make[1]: *** [../util/makedefs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rzhilich/Projects/NetHack-Android/src'
make: *** [nethack] Error 2
```

### UPD2

Apparently installation instruction isn't complete. For some reason **util** folder is not build using Android NDK gcc, but with system default **cc**. After installing following packages:

- gcc-4.6
- gcc-4.6-multilib
- gcc-arm-linux-androideabi

I've set system default gcc version to 4.6 using `update-alternatives`. And it solved my issue.

Comment: Could you please add the complete rule that generates that error ? I have an idea of what is causing you trouble...

Comment: Mmh, sorry, I though it was a makefile that **you** wrote. I had a look at the readme. Are you sure you are editing the correct file (`Makefile.src`) ? This seems to be a complex build procedure where different files are used to produce the "final" makefile.

Comment: I guess you mean 'install' rule in makefile? Here's link https://github.com/gurrhack/NetHack-Android/blob/master/sys/android/Makefile.top#L232

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I'm modifying correct make file.

Answer (score 0):

see how `iw` 
http://z4ziggy.wordpress.com/category/aircrack/

and `tcpdump` are built
https://github.com/chatch/tcpdump-android.git

The important thing is

```
    echo "| CREATING TOOLCHAIN |"
```